# Ask if an object exists in Flutter Firebase, check cache when offline

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Flutter application that uses Firebase Cloud Firestore, and I need to check if an item exists in a collection.

```
var tx = await Firestore.instance.collection(collection).document(txId).get();
return tx.exists;
```

This app is expected to be able to work offline, which is a common scenario. In that case, I would like Firestore to look up in the local store and return null if it doesn't exist. But I am having trouble with that.

I enabled Firestore persistence.

```
 Firestore.instance.settings(persistenceEnabled: true);
```

But I get the following exception:

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing get, Failed to get document because the client is offline., null)

My Firebase dependency in pubspec.yaml:

```
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
```

Is there a way I could get the desired behavior? (check only in local storage if offline)

I have been reading other questions:

[Using Offline Persistence in Firestore in a Flutter App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549773/using-offline-persistence-in-firestore-in-a-flutter-app)

But it is not exactly what I'm looking for since I don't need to write in the database.

Comment: im not what you mean. but on the latest version on flutterfire packages it now checked if the document doesnt exist and return some error*. but u can try this one incase
DocumentReference docRef = await Firestore.instance.collection(collection).document(txId);
         await docRef.get().then((docResult) {
          if (docResult.exists) {
            // some codes docResult.data
          } else {
            // doc does not exist
          }
        });

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: per the stackoveflow post you shared, you don't need to use await when working with offline persistence