# If I use firestore offline to store the data for the chat app, do I still need sqlite, flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna create a chatapp for my friend, and now remote serve I will use firestore and locally sqlite, but I realized it is default for firestore to save data offline, so my question is I have some data like message, or sending setting for the app, is it ok just to save them in firestore offline which seems automatically and no extra costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want or need.

If you want to use the offline persistance only for storing in case internet is not there at all. Firebase supports that out of the box. But you need to keep in mind to do you calls carefully. Because on a slow internet connection, if you tell the Firebase access to wait for the online behavior. It will not be using the local first and you might not be able to show the data. [Check the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53551036/1744873)

Also if you want to use the offline persistance from Firebase, be mindful that the data size has a default of 40 megabytes of limit. You might assign that by your self. [You can check this link](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#access-data-offline)

BUT, if you want to have heavy data manipulations and have more control over your data SQLite is more suggested.

My opionion: I think Firebase Offline persistance would be enough for you, so go for it.

Comment: Any progress? Please consider accepting the answer if it helps you?